# Rails: link_to_remote update doesn't render the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, rjs

I have a link_to_remote to render the edit action of an object. But all it does is update the Dom Element with this response

```
try { } catch (e) { alert('RJS error:\n\n' + e.toString()); alert(''); throw e }
```

My link looks like this:

```
= link_to_remote t("txt.edit"), :update => dom_id(comment), :url => edit_comment_path(comment.id)
```

My edit action in the comment controller:

```
  # GET /comments/1/edit
  def edit
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js { render :action => "edit" }
    end
  end
```

The request seems to be ok, according to the log:

```
Processing CommentsController#edit (for 127.0.0.1 at 2009-04-08 18:55:36) [GET]
  Session ID: 1d4b9b3d3319d5cd556d00d2e053b651
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"5d70f9e5beded361ee7e87ee591512411e8f3eec", "id"=>"18"}
  User Columns (2.0ms)   SHOW FIELDS FROM `users`
  User Load (0.5ms)   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1
  Account Columns (1.6ms)   SHOW FIELDS FROM `accounts`
  Account Load (0.2ms)   SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE (`accounts`.`subdomain` = 'xxx') LIMIT 1
  Comment Columns (1.7ms)   SHOW FIELDS FROM `comments`
  Comment Load (0.6ms)   SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE (`comments`.`id` = 18) 
Rendering comments/edit
Completed in 30818ms (View: 2, DB: 7) | 200 OK [http://xx.xxx.rails/comments/18/edit?authenticity_token=5d70f9e5beded361ee7e87ee591512411e8f3eec]
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for the help!

UPDATE:
It works by the way with a RJS template - that's how I solved it now. But I still prefer a solution where a view is rendered. Otherwise I have to create a partial just for this purpose (I cannot render Views with rjs page updates - at least I don't know how).

Answer (score 1):

Or do not catch "respond_to" at all since in both cases You are doing the same! Just comment out:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js { render :action => "edit" }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
:script => true
```

Add this to the `link_to_remote` call and it should make rails evaluate any scripts returned, rather than outputting them plain-text.

Answer (score 0):

The one thing you neglected to mention is what the template is... I'm guessing that's the problem. If it's ERB try something like:

> format.js { render :action => "edit.html.erb" }

Comment: I's a haml template, so should I try: render :action => "edit.haml" ?

Comment: Just use the full name of the template. Usually it should be 'action.mime.renderer', so like 'edit.html.haml' should be both the file name and what you send to 'render'

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have forgotten to include a reference to the Javascript libraries in your views, and the view is rendering the literal JavaScript instead of interpreting it.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

Comment: Nope, I included them all, otherwise the replacing wouldn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

When you are responding to a js request, `render :action => "edit"` will try to render edit.rjs, a rjs 'template', not edit.haml, an html template.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the :update option from your RJS tag.  I had one in there and when I was trying to insert_html it was displaying the JS returned from the method and not executing it on the DOM.  So it was displaying => try {...}

I took the :update attribute out of my link_to_remote statement in my view, used a 
`render: update do |page|
page.insert_html(...)
end` block and it executed the JS returned instead of displaying it.

Hope that helps.